# React function calling and accessing variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to access an state outside of function in React

All i am trying to do is on clicking on save i need to get all the details in form and submit through API,

The below is my full code and i have only removed the imported component details ,

What we need is when click on the save , The form should submit through the API Call

Here is my code:

````
**
function save() {
  let contactid=editcontacts.id;
  const updateapi=axios.create({baseURL:"https://108.248.238.235/TiaraDeskAPI/api/v1/contacts/"+contactid})
    let name = editcontacts.contact_name
    let email =editcontacts.email
    let phone = editcontacts.phone
    let address = editcontacts.address
    let city = editcontacts.city
    let state = editcontacts.state
    let country = editcontacts.country
    let pincode = editcontacts.zipcode
    let accountid=selected[0].id;
    //const notes = document.getElementById('input-notes').value
    const json={"account" : accountid,"contact_name" : name, "email" : email,"phone" :phone, "street" : address, "city" : city, "state" : state, "country" : country, "zipcode" : pincode};
    
    console.log(json);
    api.post("/",json,options).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.message);
    
    })
}
**

const EdittableData = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [lookuplist, setaccount2] = React.useState([]);
  const [editcontacts, setaccount] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://18.28.238.25/TI/api/v1/contacts/1/"+contactid})
  const accountapi=axios.create({baseURL:"https://18.48.28.25/TI/api/v1/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}
  //let id = useParams();
  console.log(params.id);
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await api.get("/",options);
    const response2 = await accountapi.get("/",options);

    setLoading(false);
  }, []); 



  if (loading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }    
 
  return(
    <>
     <Form>
            
                <h6 className="heading-small text-muted mb-4">
                  Contact Information
                </h6>
                <div className="pl-lg-4">
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg="12">
                      <FormGroup>
                        <label
                          className="form-control-label"
                          htmlFor="input-username"
                        >
                          Contact Name
                        </label>
                        <Input
                          className="form-control-alternative"
                        
                          id="input-username"
                          placeholder="Username"
                          type="text"
                          defaultValue={editcontacts.contact_name}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                 
                  </Row>
                 
               
                
                </div>
               
              </Form>
    
    </>
  ) 
 }

const Viewcontact = () => {
 
  
  return (
    <>
    
    <Header />
    {/* Page content */}
    <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
    
             

***************
                  <Button
                    color="primary"
                    href="#pablo"
                   onClick={save}
                    size="sm"
                  >
                    Edit
                  </Button>
*****************
           
       
     
      </>
  
  )};
export default Viewcontact;
```

I am trying to call function save in react and access the states but failed,

The error is , I cant able to access any states or variables, can you help me please

Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward solution is to put your `save()` function and your submit button (in your case 'Edit' button) inside EditableData component. It is a good practice to put your submit buttons inside forms.

```
const EdittableData = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [lookuplist, setaccount2] = React.useState([]);
  const [editcontacts, setaccount] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://18.28.238.25/TI/api/v1/contacts/1/"+contactid})
  const accountapi=axios.create({baseURL:"https://18.48.28.25/TI/api/v1/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}
  //let id = useParams();
  console.log(params.id);
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await api.get("/",options);
    const response2 = await accountapi.get("/",options);

    setLoading(false);
  }, []); 

    function save() {
    let contactid = editcontacts.id;
    const updateapi = axios.create({
      baseURL:
        "https://108.248.238.235/TiaraDeskAPI/api/v1/contacts/" + contactid
    });
    let name = editcontacts.contact_name;
    let email = editcontacts.email;
    let phone = editcontacts.phone;
    let address = editcontacts.address;
    let city = editcontacts.city;
    let state = editcontacts.state;
    let country = editcontacts.country;
    let pincode = editcontacts.zipcode;
    let accountid = selected[0].id;
    //const notes = document.getElementById('input-notes').value
    const json = {
      account: accountid,
      contact_name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      street: address,
      city: city,
      state: state,
      country: country,
      zipcode: pincode
    };

    console.log(json);
    api.post("/", json, options).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.message);
    });
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }    
 
  return(
    <>
     <Form>
            
                <h6 className="heading-small text-muted mb-4">
                  Contact Information
                </h6>
                <div className="pl-lg-4">
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg="12">
                      <FormGroup>
                        <label
                          className="form-control-label"
                          htmlFor="input-username"
                        >
                          Contact Name
                        </label>
                        <Input
                          className="form-control-alternative"
                        
                          id="input-username"
                          placeholder="Username"
                          type="text"
                          defaultValue={editcontacts.contact_name}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                 
                  </Row>
                 
               
                
                </div>
                <Button color="primary" href="#pablo" onClick={save} size="sm">
                  Edit
                </Button>;
              </Form>
    
    </>
  ) 
 }
```

Comment: If i put save() function and your submit button (in your case 'Edit' button) inside EditableData component. The function is not calling it says an error "save" not defined

Comment: Could you add a code snippet that demonstrates your answer?

Comment: I added a snippet. Both save function and submit button are in the EditableData component.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access state of an outside component. If you wish to access state outside of component, you can check [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (shared state for multiple components).

However, your can reconsider your approach: should you be able to call `<EdittableData  />` inside `<Viewcontact />`, you could put all your form's state and `save()` function inside `<ViewContact />` component. Then you can pass your state down to `<EdittableData>` as `props`. This way, `save()` function and `<EdittableData>` component will have access to same state.